# Exclude posts with specific meta_value while sorting by a separate meta_value

Tags: posts, wp-query, sort, exclude

I am trying to exclude posts with a specific meta_value with a specific meta_key while also sorting the posts by a meta_value with a different meta_key.

This is my current code for the WP_Query class:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'meta_key' => 'release_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

the sorting by a specific meta_value part is working fine but I am not sure what to add to get it to exclude posts with a specific meta_value with a different meta_key than the one used for sorting.

Any advice / help is very much appreciated.

**I got this working with the code below:**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'meta_key' => 'release_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'undetermined_date',
            'value' => 'TBA',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have changed the custom field type to check-boxes which returns true or false instead of a text box. How would I change this code for use with a check-boxes? Here is the code I have tried:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'meta_key' => 'release_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'undetermined_date_toggle',
            'value' => 'true',
            'compare' => '==',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: If this is the main query, use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) rather than create a new query.

Comment: So is this still an open question?

Comment: @Milo could you please explain how I would use pre_got_posts instead of meta_query for this?

Comment: @toscho This question is still open.

Comment: @RipzCurlz - it's not a question of pre_get_posts *or* meta_query, both would be meta queries, it's just a matter of *where and when* you're doing the query. if this is meant to replace the main query on an archive page, you should modify it *before* the query happens, which is before the template is loaded, this is done via pre_get_posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code may be

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'meta_key' => 'release_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'undetermined_date_toggle',
            'value' => 'true',
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

this code show only those posts which have `undetermined_date_toggle key==true`
or has checkbox check (selected) sorted by release_date_key.

**Important Link**:

[WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

*In meta_query parameter compare and type as your requirement not necessary to pass they have their default values `=` and `CHAR`, for more info read WordPress codex for WP_Query