# Hide posts with meta key in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

I was reading [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101899/exclude-posts-with-specific-meta-value-while-sorting-by-a-separate-meta-value) to "Exclude posts with specific meta_value" but it does not work correctly. Here is the arguments I am passing to `WP_Query` :

```
      $args=array(
        'cat' => $catid,
        'category__in'=> $term_ids,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured_post',
                'value' => 'on',
            ),
        ),
      );
```

Using the above method, I can list posts which use meta key, but I do not want posts, with meta key "featured_post" to be displayed. If I change the `value` to something else then no post is displayed.

The meta value is simply a check box for featured posts.

Comment: I believe you are missing your `compare` argument for the `meta_query`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `compare` with `NOT EXISTS` to get posts without that meta key.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'featured_post',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
)
```

Comment: thanks, it works, stupid me I checked the meta key in the post and I thought otherwise.

Comment: a related question, if I have something like [this](http://pastebin.com/mU7ZGJKs) where I am trying to get post with meta key, if I have multiple posts with meta key in same category, all of them are displayed. Is it possible to only display 1 post with meta key based on date? (considering we have many of them)

Comment: change `posts_per_page` to `1` instead of `-1`. `-1` returns all.

Comment: yes, but I have several categories, if I change it to `1` then only 1 post from a category is displayed. I want the post with meta key from each category to be displayed.

Comment: so something like [this](http://pastebin.com/YUAY2sA9) where [this](http://pastebin.com/mU7ZGJKs) is used for this section.  So the recent post published under Grand children categories which has meta key.

Comment: You can't (easily) get a post per-category with a single standard WP_Query. I think that question has been asked before if you search around here.